# Display Ember library versions in browser console on app load

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

For some reason, I am having trouble remembering (or finding) how to turn on an option to display versions of ember, jquery, ember-data, etc. in the console automatically. Used to be very handy.

I am on Ember-CLI 0.2.7.

Ended up doing this in app.js:

```
import config from './config/environment';

if (config.environment !== 'development') {
  Ember.LOG_VERSION = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// app/app.js
Ember.LOG_VERSION = true;
```

LOG_VERSION determines whether Ember logs info about version of used libraries. `True` by default

http://emberjs.com/api/#property_LOG_VERSION